# How to handle files committed to Git on Linux with invalid Windows filenames?

Tags: windows, linux, git

I committed some files with a name containing ':' and '"' characters, which are invalid on Windows. When I try to git pull from a Windows machine it gives me an error message.

Is there a way to rename these files on the repo from the Windows machine? Or is there any other workaround?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't clone the repo onto a Linux machine, rename the files, commit, and push?

Comment: I don't have access to a Linux machine where I am at the moment. Is there a way to do it from a Windows machine?

Comment: I don't have a windows machine to fiddle on. How does the pull fail? Is it in a merge conflict state, where it's fetched the content but can't commit, or does it simply refuse to try? (And is the merge a fast-forward or not?)

Comment: I would recommend doing a `git fetch` instead of `git pull` and trying to work around the problem by only checking out commits which predate the rename.

Comment: Using [git filter-repo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43762489/1509695) to rewrite the history to exclude those file names may also be an approach, but not sure about affecting other users of the same repository in that case.

Answer (score 4):

If you have an access to a linux machine you can rename it, do the according changes into the code, and push to the repository (with appropriate comment)

Comment: This also works with the Ubuntu Bash on Windows if you clone the repo to /tmp

Comment: @endolith: Clone the repo first, then change the clone ? Incidentially, send a pull-request, while you are at it.

Answer (score 3):

You could try doing a "sparse checkout" so that you don't check out those files on Windows.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/13738951/316578

Of course, this only works for you if it's okay not to have those files present on Windows.

Comment: Thanks for the link! Very helpful.